# Compress series of close numbers in C

Tags: c, time-series, compression

I have a number of time series each containing a sequence of 400 numbers that are close to each other.  I have thousands of time series; each has its own series of close numbers.

TimeSeries1 = 184.56, 184.675, 184.55, 184.77, ...

TimeSeries2 = 145.73, 145.384, 145.96, 145.33, ...

TimeSeries3 = -126.48, -126.78, -126.55, ...

I can store an 8 byte double for each time Series, so for *most* of the time series, I can compress each double to a single byte by multiplying by 100 and  taking the delta of the current value and the previous value.
Here is my compress/decompress code:

```
struct{
    double firstValue;
    double nums[400];
    char compressedNums[400];
    int compressionOK;
} timeSeries;

void compress(void){
    timeSeries.firstValue = timeSeries.nums[0];
    double lastValue = timeSeries.firstValue;
    for (int i = 1; i < 400; ++i){ 
        int delta = (int) ((timeSeries.nums[i] * 100) - (lastValue* 100));

        timeSeries.compressionOK = 1;
        if (delta > CHAR_MAX || delta < -CHAR_MAX){
            timeSeries.compressionOK = 0;
            return;
        }
        else{       
            timeSeries.compressedNums[i] = (char) delta;
            lastValue = timeSeries.nums[i];
        }
    }
}   

double decompressedNums[400];    

void decompress(void){
    if (timeSeries.compressionOK){
        double lastValue = timeSeries.firstValue;

        for (int i = 1; i < 400; ++i){
            decompressedNums[i] = lastValue + timeSeries.compressedNums[i] / 100.0;
            lastValue = decompressedNums[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I can tolerate *some* lossiness, on the order of .005 per number.  However, I am getting more loss than I can tolerate, especially since a precision loss in one of the compressed series carries forward and causes an increasing amount of loss.

So my questions are:

1. Is there something I can change to reduce the lossiness?
2. Is there an altogether different compression method that has a comparable, or better, than this 8 to 1 ratio?

Comment: You should probably be using explicit `signed char compressedNums[400];` since plain `char` can be signed or unsigned.

Comment: Note that if the difference between successive values is more than ±1.27, your compression scheme won't work well.  Obviously, you can spot that while compressing, and you'd need to know how to handle it.  You could instead use `short` which would allow ±320 between successive values (with a resolution of 0.01 — or ±32 with a resolution of 0.001).  If the deltas between successive values are small enough, you should get close to perfect behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should round the values before converting to an `int` to avoid the problems, as in this code.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { TS_SIZE = 400 };

typedef struct
{
    double firstValue;
    double nums[TS_SIZE];
    signed char compressedNums[TS_SIZE];
    int compressionOK;
} timeSeries;

static
void compress(timeSeries *t1)
{
    t1->firstValue = t1->nums[0];
    double lastValue = t1->firstValue;
    for (int i = 1; i < TS_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        int delta = (int) round((t1->nums[i] - lastValue) * 100.0);

        t1->compressionOK = 1;
        if (delta > CHAR_MAX || delta < -CHAR_MAX)
        {
            printf("Delta too big: %d (%.3f) vs %d (%.3f) = delta %.3f\n",
                    i-1, t1->nums[i-1], i, t1->nums[i], t1->nums[i] - t1->nums[i-1]);
            t1->compressionOK = 0;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            t1->compressedNums[i] = (char) delta;
            lastValue = t1->nums[i];
        }
    }
}

static
void decompress(timeSeries *t1)
{
    if (t1->compressionOK)
    {
        double lastValue = t1->firstValue;

        for (int i = 1; i < TS_SIZE; ++i)
        {
            t1->nums[i] = lastValue + t1->compressedNums[i] / 100.0;
            lastValue = t1->nums[i];
        }
    }
}

static void compare(const timeSeries *t0, const timeSeries *t1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TS_SIZE; i++)
    {
        char c = (fabs(t0->nums[i] - t1->nums[i]) > 0.005) ? '!' : ' ';
        printf("%c %03d: %.3f vs %.3f = %+.3f\n", c, i, t0->nums[i], t1->nums[i], t0->nums[i] - t1->nums[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    timeSeries t1;
    timeSeries t0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < TS_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%lf", &t0.nums[i]) != 1)
            break;
    }
    if (i != TS_SIZE)
    {
        printf("Reading problems\n");
        return 1;
    }

    t1 = t0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Cycle %d:\n", i+1);
        compress(&t1);
        decompress(&t1);
        compare(&t0, &t1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the following data (generated from integers in the range 18456..18855 divided by 100 and randomly perturbed by a small amount (about 0.3%, to keep the values close enough together), I got the same data over, and over again, for the full 10 cycles of compression and decompression.

```
184.60 184.80 184.25 184.62 184.49 184.94 184.95 184.39 184.50 184.96
184.54 184.72 184.84 185.02 184.83 185.01 184.43 185.00 184.74 184.88
185.04 184.79 184.55 184.94 185.07 184.60 184.55 184.57 184.95 185.07
184.61 184.57 184.57 184.98 185.24 185.11 184.89 184.72 184.77 185.29
184.98 184.91 184.76 184.89 185.26 184.94 185.09 184.68 184.69 185.04
185.39 185.05 185.41 185.41 184.74 184.77 185.16 184.84 185.31 184.90
185.18 185.15 185.03 185.41 185.18 185.25 185.01 185.31 185.36 185.29
185.62 185.48 185.40 185.15 185.29 185.19 185.32 185.60 185.39 185.22
185.66 185.48 185.53 185.59 185.27 185.69 185.29 185.70 185.77 185.40
185.41 185.23 185.84 185.30 185.70 185.18 185.68 185.43 185.45 185.71
185.60 185.82 185.92 185.40 185.85 185.65 185.92 185.80 185.60 185.57
185.64 185.39 185.48 185.36 185.69 185.76 185.45 185.72 185.47 186.04
185.81 185.80 185.94 185.64 186.09 185.95 186.03 185.55 185.65 185.75
186.03 186.02 186.24 186.19 185.62 186.13 185.98 185.84 185.83 186.19
186.17 185.80 186.15 186.10 186.32 186.25 186.09 186.20 186.06 185.80
186.02 186.40 186.26 186.15 186.35 185.90 185.98 186.19 186.15 185.84
186.34 186.20 186.41 185.93 185.97 186.46 185.92 186.19 186.15 186.32
186.06 186.25 186.47 186.56 186.47 186.33 186.55 185.98 186.36 186.35
186.65 186.60 186.52 186.13 186.39 186.55 186.50 186.45 186.29 186.24
186.81 186.61 186.80 186.60 186.75 186.83 186.86 186.35 186.34 186.53
186.60 186.69 186.32 186.23 186.39 186.71 186.65 186.37 186.37 186.54
186.81 186.84 186.78 186.50 186.47 186.44 186.36 186.59 186.87 186.70
186.90 186.47 186.50 186.74 186.80 186.86 186.72 186.63 186.78 186.52
187.22 186.71 186.56 186.90 186.95 186.67 186.79 186.99 186.85 187.03
187.04 186.89 187.19 187.33 187.09 186.92 187.35 187.29 187.04 187.00
186.79 187.32 186.94 187.07 186.92 187.06 187.39 187.20 187.35 186.78
187.47 187.54 187.33 187.07 187.39 186.97 187.48 187.10 187.52 187.55
187.06 187.24 187.28 186.92 187.60 187.05 186.95 187.26 187.08 187.35
187.24 187.66 187.57 187.75 187.15 187.08 187.55 187.30 187.17 187.17
187.13 187.14 187.40 187.71 187.64 187.32 187.42 187.19 187.40 187.66
187.93 187.27 187.44 187.35 187.34 187.54 187.70 187.62 187.99 187.97
187.51 187.36 187.82 187.75 187.56 187.53 187.38 187.91 187.63 187.51
187.39 187.54 187.69 187.84 188.16 187.61 188.03 188.06 187.53 187.51
187.93 188.04 187.77 187.69 188.03 187.81 188.04 187.82 188.14 187.96
188.05 187.63 188.35 187.65 188.00 188.27 188.20 188.21 187.81 188.04
187.87 187.96 188.18 187.98 188.46 187.89 187.77 188.18 187.83 188.03
188.48 188.09 187.82 187.90 188.40 188.32 188.33 188.29 188.58 188.53
187.88 188.32 188.57 188.14 188.02 188.25 188.62 188.43 188.19 188.54
188.20 188.06 188.31 188.19 188.48 188.44 188.69 188.63 188.34 188.76
188.32 188.82 188.45 188.34 188.44 188.25 188.39 188.83 188.49 188.18
```

Until I put the rounding in, the values would rapidly drift apart.

---

If you don't have `round()` — which was added to Standard C in the C99 standard — then you can use these lines in place of `round()`:

```
int delta;
if (t1->nums[i] > lastValue)
    delta = (int) (((t1->nums[i] - lastValue) * 100.0) + 0.5);
else
    delta = (int) (((t1->nums[i] - lastValue) * 100.0) - 0.5);
```

This rounds correctly for positive and negative values.  You could also factor that into a function; in C99, you could make it an `inline` function, but if that worked, you would have the `round()` function in the library, too.  I used this code at first before switching to the `round()` function.

Comment: That works.  Unfortunately I'm still on VS2012, which has no round function.  But I achieved the same thing by: int val1 = (int) (currentValue * 100); int val2 = (int) (lastValue*100); then delta = val1 - val2.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the slow drift in precision by working out the delta not from the precise value of the previous element, but rather from the computed approximation of the previous element (i.e. the sum of the deltas). That way, you will always get the closest approximation to the next value.

Personally, I'd use integer arithmetic for this purpose, but it will probably be fine with floating point arithmetic too, since floating point is reproducible even if not precise.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the values as stored in memory:

```
184.   == 0x4067000000000000ull
184.56 == 0x406711eb851eb852ull
```

The first two bytes are the same but the last six bytes are different.

For integer deltas, multiply by 128 instead of 100, this will get you 7 bits of the fractional part. If the delta is too large for one byte use a three byte sequence {0x80, hi_delta, lo_delta}, so 0x80 is used a special indicator. If the delta happened to be -128, then that would be {0x80, 0xff, 0x80}.